# How to iterate over a large text file(906.2MB) in Python?

Tags: python, twitter

This is the code snippet I am using

```
tweets_data=[]
with open('/home/surya/tweet2.txt','r') as f:
   while True:
      next_n_lines= list(islice(f,10000))
      if not next_n_lines:
         break
      for line in next_n_lines:
         try:
             tweet= json.loads(line)
             tweets_data.append(tweet)
         except:
             continue
print(len(tweets_data))
```

Here I have used islice from itertools package in Python to loop line by line through chunks rather than the whloe file at a go. I have used an array tweets_data because later I plan to use it to do some analysis using matplotlib.

I have tested the code on a 119.2 MB of the same file and it takes around 30 seconds but on the 906.2MB file, my Ubuntu hangs up and I am forced terminate the process after waiting long.

This is the format of my **tweet.txt** file

```
{"created_at":"Thu Jun 16 15:44:22 +0000 2016","id":743469273415311360,"id_str":"743469273415311360","text":"RT @itvnews: This is how the fans in Lens reacted as Daniel Sturridge scored the winning #ENG goal #ENGWAL #EURO2016\nhttps:\/\/t.co\/7uta44gRh1","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/android\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for Android\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":29464323,"id_str":"29464323","name":"Darren Roberts","screen_name":"Darren081969","location":"Kent England","url":null,"description":null,"protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":14,"friends_count":49,"listed_count":0,"favourites_count":9,"statuses_count":9,"created_at":"Tue Apr 07 14:58:50 +0000 2009","utc_offset":3600,"time_zone":"London","geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"1A1B1F","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme9\/bg.gif","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme9\/bg.gif","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"2FC2EF","profile_sidebar_border_color":"181A1E","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"252429","profile_text_color":"666666","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/742699562217943041\/e87qqP_5_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/742699562217943041\/e87qqP_5_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/29464323\/1465908742","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweeted_status":{"created_at":"Thu Jun 16 15:39:45 +0000 2016","id":743468111282659328,"id_str":"743468111282659328","text":"This is how the fans in Lens reacted as Daniel Sturridge scored the winning #ENG goal #ENGWAL #EURO2016\nhttps:\/\/t.co\/7uta44gRh1","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":21866939,"id_str":"21866939","name":"ITV News","screen_name":"itvnews","location":"United Kingdom","url":"http:\/\/www.itv.com\/news","description":"Breaking news and the biggest stories from the UK and around the world. Bulletins weekdays at 1:30pm, 6:30pm and 10pm on ITV. Email yourstory@itv.com","protected":false,"verified":true,"followers_count":1447643,"friends_count":1371,"listed_count":5097,"favourites_count":245,"statuses_count":142011,"created_at":"Wed Feb 25 13:51:23 +0000 2009","utc_offset":3600,"time_zone":"London","geo_enabled":true,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"006473","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/766810747\/a53a8d9148ca55ff82b713b6a9631fe7.jpeg","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/766810747\/a53a8d9148ca55ff82b713b6a9631fe7.jpeg","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_link_color":"006473","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDFFCC","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/3105933720\/17bab587f151975ca4ae9f6a1cab7c56_normal.png","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/3105933720\/17bab587f151975ca4ae9f6a1cab7c56_normal.png","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/21866939\/1398434757","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":53,"favorite_count":67,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"ENG","indices":[76,80]},{"text":"ENGWAL","indices":[86,93]},{"text":"EURO2016","indices":[94,103]}],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/7uta44gRh1","expanded_url":"https:\/\/amp.twimg.com\/v\/a4cdb597-bde4-4523-8cf6-591d823723c8","display_url":"amp.twimg.com\/v\/a4cdb597-bde\u2026","indices":[104,127]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en"},"is_quote_status":false,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"ENG","indices":[89,93]},{"text":"ENGWAL","indices":[99,106]},{"text":"EURO2016","indices":[107,116]}],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/7uta44gRh1","expanded_url":"https:\/\/amp.twimg.com\/v\/a4cdb597-bde4-4523-8cf6-591d823723c8","display_url":"amp.twimg.com\/v\/a4cdb597-bde\u2026","indices":[117,140]}],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"itvnews","name":"ITV News","id":21866939,"id_str":"21866939","indices":[3,11]}],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1466091862430"}
```

What I am trying to achieve with my code is trying to fing out the number of tweets I have in the **tweet.txt** file. Any suggestion for a faster way to iterate or a different approach is welcome. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: `wc -l /home/surya/tweet2.txt`

Comment: If all you want is the count, `wc -l tweet.txt`. If the count is just a step towards a bigger goal, you'll have to find some way not to load everything into memory.

Comment: You might want to look into [memory-mapping the file](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/mmap.html).

Comment: @Thomas yes storing into the array is just a part of a bigger goal which is to do some data analysis

Comment: I'm also a bit unclear on why you load 10000 lines at a time to memory in a list instead of just doing `for line in f:`. You'll be using quite a bit of memory this way anyway, since you deserialize the json to the list.

Comment: Are you running out of memory? Is all you need a count?

Comment: What you are doing with `islice` is **useless**. Just do `for line in f: data.append(json.loads(line))`.

Comment: If I just use 'for line in f:' wouldn't it even be slower.....I tested 'for line in f:' on the 119. 2 MB file and it was slower than the above code @IljaEverilä

Comment: @CodeRabbit Did you try to see where the problem is? AFAIK I believe the problem is the time taken to convert all the lines to json objects, not the time taken to read the file.

Comment: That may be, but is it really the limiting part in your analysis? Premature optimization and all that. Naturally if it really is a show stopper, then your islice is the way to go for that particular part of the problem.

Comment: @Bakuriu Can you suggest a different way?

Comment: @CodeRabbit if speed is what are you looking for and you are a spare gigabyte of ram try to memory map it with mmap.

Comment: Did a simple `yes '{"the_key": "To success... Is having this and that and those and well.. All of it.", "the_answer": 42}' | head -n3000000 > alotofjson.json` resulting in 295M of JSON. Unserialized it in python, resulting in RSS rising to 1,6GiB. Your 906MiB of JSON unserialized is prolly eating up your memory and pushing you to swap, unless you have a *lot* of ram.

Comment: 983MiB file, 5,3GiB RSS. Not insurmountable, but could be the issue. The memory requirements may and do differ for your tweets.

Comment: @IljaEverilä It is then probably eating up my memory, so what do you suggest for a solution ? memory mapping using mmap?

Comment: @CodeRabbit if the memory usage is the problem (and most of the lines are valid JSON lines), then you have a bigger problem than iteration.
After loading JSON string, it becomes a dictionary, which consumes more memory than the original string.

Comment: That'd depend on your analysis. Do you need all of the tweet data? You could store only the bits and parts you need in order to reduce the dataset to a manageable size.

Comment: @CodeRabbit try to reduce size of the stored information - if only several records of the dictionary are important to you, extract them just after parsing the JSON, then discard the dictionary

Comment: To have all information stored, probably database (even sqlite) would be good solution here. Easy access with ORM to every data piece and can load only relevant information into memory.

Answer (score 2):

If the memory usage is a problem, iterate over the file itself:

```
for line in f:
    # your code here
```

If you have a lot of memory, iterate over the `.readlines()` list:

```
for line in f.readlines():
    # your code here
```